SQL QUERY reporting production yield by time range Group by
Hi I am new to the SQL world. I want to calculate the system on and off time and total production yield of each run time. Thanks.
Here is exmple of the raw data.



timestamp
system status
yield lbs/s




2024-07-15 02:14:01
0
0


2024-07-15 02:14:02
1
150


2024-07-15 02:14:03
1
150


2024-07-15 02:14:04
0
0


2024-07-15 02:14:05
0
0


2024-07-15 02:14:06
0
0


2024-07-15 02:14:07
0
0


2024-07-15 02:14:08
1
50


2024-07-15 02:14:09
1
50


2024-07-15 02:14:10
1
150


2024-07-15 02:14:11
1
150


2024-07-15 02:14:12
0
0



Here is what I am expecting



system run time
system start time
system stop time
total yield lbs




1
2024-07-15 02:14:02
2024-07-15 02:14:04
300


2
2024-07-15 02:14:08
2024-07-15 02:14:12
400




WITH status_change AS (
    SELECT 
        timestamp,
        system_status,
        LAG(system_status) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) AS prev_status
    FROM my_table
),
run_intervals AS (
    SELECT 
        timestamp AS system_start_time,
        LEAD(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) AS system_stop_time,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) AS system_run_time
    FROM status_change
    WHERE system_status = 1 AND prev_status = 0
)
SELECT
    system_run_time,
    system_start_time,
    system_stop_time,
    SUM(yield_lbs_s) AS total_yield_lbs
FROM run_intervals
JOIN my_table ON my_table.timestamp BETWEEN run_intervals.system_start_time AND run_intervals.system_stop_time
GROUP BY system_run_time, system_start_time, system_stop_time
ORDER BY system_run_time;

Change my_table by real table name

Thanks Zircon. When execting your query I got only one line of result that system_start_time 2024-07-15 02:14:02 and system_stop_time  2024-07-15 02:14:08 (which is not correct. It should be 2024-07-15 02:14:04). I think both start_time and stop_time are refering the same where clause. Do you know how to solve this? Thanks.
